# Setting all elements of an array of pointers to nullptr in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers

I am just wondering if there is a way of setting an initialized array of pointers to all null values without using a loop?

```
class Abc{
  //An array of 2000 Product pointers
  Product* product_[2000];
      public:
         Abc();
}
```

I want to set all pointers to null when the constructor is called:

```
Abc::Abc(){
    product_ = {};
}
```

This does not work, product_ must be a modifiable value.
Is there an easier way than looping 2000 elements?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you got against loops?

Comment: `Abc::Abc() : product_{} {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
class Abc{
  //An array of 2000 Product pointers
  Product* product_[2000];
      public:
         Abc() : product_{} {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use std::array they'll be initialised to nullptr by default.

```
std::array<Product *, 2000> product;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio compiler you can initialize the pointers to NULL in the initializer list like below-

```
class Abc{
  //An array of 2000 Product pointers
  Product* product_[2000];
      public:
         Abc():product_(){};
}
```